# zsh: command not found: stt

Tags: sublimetext3, zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

I recently uninstalled and reinstalled oh-my-zsh on my mac after doing some updates (Mojave OS, Xcode update), and now I can't launch Sublime text using the command 'stt'. I checked the .zshrc file, and the sublime plugin seems to be there:

```
➜  / cat ~/.zshrc 
ZSH=$HOME/.oh-my-zsh

# You can change the theme with another one:
#   https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/themes
ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"

# Useful plugins for Rails development with Sublime Text
plugins=(gitfast last-working-dir common-aliases sublime zsh-syntax- 
highlighting history-substring-search)
```

I also checked my path variable:

`➜  / echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/aaronmednick/.rvm/bin`

Any idea as to why 'stt' isn't working?

Comment: The command to launch Sublime is `subl` unless you set up your own alias or symlink, but there is no evidence of that in the file you posted above unless it's part of that magic `plugins` line (I don't use `zsh` personally).

Comment: Okay weirdest thing happened. I literally walked away from my computer for 4 hours, just came back and now the 'stt' command is working...wth